# Unhandled Exception: Connection refused - Truffle Ganache Connection with Flutter

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ganache

I am getting this error when trying to link a smart contract deployed on a Ganache local blockchain with Flutter `web3dart` package.

*Note: Testing on android (both emulator and physical device give the same error)*

```
E/flutter ( 5780): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
Exception: Connection refused
E/flutter ( 5780): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:88:7)
E/flutter ( 5780): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5780): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:32)
E/flutter ( 5780): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5780): #2      JsonRPC.call (package:web3dart/json_rpc.dart:49:22)
E/flutter ( 5780): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5780): #3      Web3Client._makeRPCCall (package:web3dart/src/core/client.dart:53:20)
E/flutter ( 5780): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5780): #4      ContractLinker.initialSetup (package:cupcake_eth2/contract_linking.dart:60:16)
E/flutter ( 5780): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5780): #5      ContractLinker.contractLinking (package:cupcake_eth2/contract_linking.dart:44:5)
E/flutter ( 5780): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5780): #6      ContractLinker.onInit (package:cupcake_eth2/contract_linking.dart:16:5)
E/flutter ( 5780): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Here are my variables:

```
 final String _rpcUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:7545";
 final String _wsUrl = "ws://127.0.0.1:7545/";
```

Relevant part of `truffle_config.js`:

```
networks: {
     development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,           
      network_id: "*",       
     },
  },
```

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-and-blockchain-hello-world-dapp/)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
  final String _rpcUrl =
      Platform.isAndroid ? 'http://10.0.2.2:7545' : 'http://127.0.0.1:7545';
  final String _wsUrl =
      Platform.isAndroid ? 'http://10.0.2.2:7545' : 'ws://127.0.0.1:7545';
```

instead of

```
final String _rpcUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:7545";
final String _wsUrl = "ws://127.0.0.1:7545/";
```

Comment: What is this ? What is that ? How does it solve the problem ?

Comment: Check it again i have changed the answer